# Isaac application terminated unexpectedly : [V4L2Camera] Error: driver has changed pixel format to: 1196444237

Tags: video, camera, nvidia

I get the following error when running V4L2 sample or any other one involving V4L2 :

```
2020-04-29 08:30:21.403 PANIC packages/sensors/V4L2Camera.cpp@149: 
[V4L2Camera] Error: driver has changed pixel format to: 1196444237
Isaac application terminated unexpectedly
```

With following driver parameters :

```
"config": {
"v4l2_camera": {
  "driver": {
    "device_id": 0,
    "rows": 240,
    "cols": 640,
    "rate_hz": 60
  }
},
```

I tryed specifing color space but did nothing :

```
enum ColorSpace {
greyscale @0;
rgb @1;
bgr @2;
yuv @3;
rgba @4;
}
```

I am using a stereo camera
MJPEG:2560X960@ 60fps/2560X720@60fps /1280X480@60fps/640X240@60fps 
(http://www.webcamerausb.com/elp-synchronization-dual-undistortion-lens-usb-camera-module-lens-mjpeg-60fps-2560x960-ov9750-cmos-stereo-webcam-hd-for-3d-vr-camera-p-286.html)

The camera work perfectly in vlc with the following bash and parameters :

```
 vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

With vlc auto detecting following parameters :

```
Codec MJPEC
Resolution 2560x960
Decoded format Planar 4:2:2 YUV full scale
```

When I use v4l2 utils I get :

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
Name        : Motion-JPEG
    Size: Discrete 2560x960
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 2560x720
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 1280x480
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    Size: Discrete 640x240
        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

Format Video Capture:

```
Width/Height      : 2560/960
Pixel Format      : 'MJPG'
Field             : None
Bytes per Line    : 0
Size Image        : 4915200
Colorspace        : sRGB
Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
```

I found this parameter but don’t know where to put it : V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG

Thank you a lot !